# Error in the most simplest example in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am testing the example here: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/overview/

```
using Flux
actual(x) = 4x + 2
x_train, x_test= hcat(0:5...), hcat(6:10...)
y_train, y_test = actual.(x_train), actual.(x_test)

predict = Dense(1 => 1)
predict(x_train)

loss(x,y) = Flux.Losses.mse(predict(x),y)
loss(x_train,y_train)

using Flux:train!
opt = Descent(0.1)
data = [(x_train, y_train)]

parameters = Flux.params(predict)
predict.weight in parameters, predict.bias in parameters

train!(loss, parameters, data, opt)

loss(x_train, y_train)

for epoch in 1:1000
    train!(loss, parameters, data, opt)
end

loss(x_train, y_train)

predict(x_test)
y_test
```

As you can see, it is just a very simple model actual(x) = 4x + 2. If you run these codes you will get an almost perfect prediction result.

> 1×5 Matrix{Float32}:
> 26.0001  30.0001  34.0001  38.0001  42.0001

> 1×5 Matrix{Int64}:
> 26  30  34  38  42

But if I make a minor change in term of feeding the model with one more data, like this:

```
x_train, x_test= hcat(0:6...), hcat(6:10...)
```

So I didn't change anything except line 3. I just changed 5 to 6.
Then the prediction result will become infinite.

> 1×5 Matrix{Float32}:
> NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

> 1×5 Matrix{Int64}:
> 26  30  34  38  42

But why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is simply a case of a high learning rate gone wrong. I can reproduce the same `NaN` behaviour with `Descent(0.1)`. I tried printing it out and the loss goes to `Inf` first before `NaN` - a classic sign of a divergence because of a high learning rate. So I tried a learning rate of 0.01 and it works just fine - it gives the expected answer. It is probably diverging when `x_train` is `hcat(0:6...)`. A smaller learning rate allows the network to take smaller steps and it manages to find the minimum as expected.